# WVD AdminUsername Change NotAllowed

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, windows-virtual-desktop

getting a strange error when deploying from a managed image in Windows Virtual Desktop

error:

```
\"message\":\"Atleastoneresourcedeploymentoperationfailed.Pleaselistdeploymentoperationsfordetails.Pleaseseehttps://aka.ms/DeployOperationsforusagedetails.\"\"details\":[\r\n{\r\n\"code\":\"Conflict\"\"message\":\"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"PropertyChangeNotAllowed\",\"message\":\"Changingproperty'adminUsername'isnotallowed.\",\"target\":\"adminUsername\
```

Any idea where I've gone wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want to manage Azure resource, you need have your subscription Owner role.

Comment: @Sajeetharan thanks for the info, I’m an RDS owner, deploying with a servicePrincipal which has RDS owner role, contributor on subscription and Global Admin, is there anything further I need to assign?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/troubleshoot-set-up-issues

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/582

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/27881

Comment: @Sajeetharan thanks so much for your help, that helped point me in the right direction, the username I was using was not valid. Please submit as answer 

Comment: glad that it worked, done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, make sure you are using the correct username.

You can refer this [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/582) for more details.

> This is likely because the local user name was 'admin', which is not
>   allowed by Azure. The name that will be used by the command can be
>   found in az vm create -h